# How do I display content in a way like UICollectionView on the web?

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm an iOS developer. I don't know anything about the web beyond basic HTML/CSS. I am trying to learn some modern web techniques by updating my personal site. My goal is to make dynamic requests to, say, the iTunes store to get all of my apps and display them in a scrollable list— as you'd do with UICollectionView on iOS.

I have no idea where to start. I find that there are zillions of web frameworks, many of which have other dependencies, and often explain what they do in terms of other frameworks' functionality.

How do I get started? I would google around but I don't even know what to search for.

**EDIT:** To be clear, I'm looking for something like the "Viewers Also Bought" section on this page:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/beetlejuice/id282447504

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your aim is dynamic content, then you will need PHP & Javascript (IMO, PHP is enough since your apps doesn't change on the spot, i.e. you don't need to update the list while the user is viewing the page).
And about showing the apps in a scrollable list, you can use HTML `<table>` tag.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have an impression of PHP as a dinosaur of a language. Is PHP/JS alone really a 'modern' approach?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "HTML tag"?

Comment: PHP/JS is a powerful approach IMO, and sorry for the HTML tag typo, I meant "HTML `<table>` tag" :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction about `<table>`! I got what I wanted with only JS in the end: charliewilliams.org